# Why is Garbage Collection so Slow?

Tags: python, pandas, garbage-collection

Profiling my code in IPython using %prun, I've noticed that the majority of the function time is spent in garbage collection (0.334s vs. 0.428 total time).

```
79254 function calls (77408 primitive calls) in 0.428 seconds

Ordered by: internal time

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     5    0.334    0.067    0.334    0.067 {gc.collect}
 15757    0.005    0.000    0.007    0.000 {isinstance}
  1584    0.002    0.000    0.004    0.000 dtypes.py:68(is_dtype)
```

I've tried disabling/enabling the garbage collection before calling the function and after returning its value, but the timing is virtually identical.

```
import gc

gc.disable()
x = foo()
gc.disable()
```

Does anyone know why this is such a bottleneck and how to speed it up?

My Python/Pandas versions are listed below:

```
Python 2.7.11 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:57:58) 
Pandas 0.17.1
```

Comment: I guess your code produces a lot oft garbage.

Comment: I guess the answer is "no", but can you share any code here? Otherwise perhaps you could write something that demonstrates this gc issue. :s

Comment: @AndyHayden I'm still profiling.  It looks like the bottleneck is a function that runs lots of regressions.  If I can put together a MVE, I'll edit my post.

Comment: Another idea, is to override `gc.collect = lambda: None` (and then put it back after!). Maybe something deeper is enabling gc and manually collecting. No idea if that'll actually work, but worth a shot.

Comment: It's been a while, just wonder if you were able to find out more in the meantime?

Comment: @stefan No, it has dropped from my priorities.  I may actually be revisiting this again soon, so I'll given an update if anything comes of it.

Comment: @Alexander did you every create an MVE of this issue?

Comment: It could be from a lib explicitly invoking `gc.collect()` -- e.g. see the source for `pandas.core.generic.NDFrame`

Answer (score 1):

Garbage collection is a high level feature/abstraction of many modern languages. It makes programs slower, but it also makes programs much less error-prone and easier to create.

Here are some good articles about this specific topic:

[Python Garbage](http://tech.oyster.com/pythons-garbage-collector/)
[Only slow if you use it wrong](http://pydanny-event-notes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/PyCodeConf2011/python_slow_if_wrong.html)

Comment: heh, only slow says `TODO: find out what he meant somehow` in the GC section

Answer (score 0):

You disabled `gc` so there might be actually something calling `gc.collect` explicitly. You can possibly find the culprit by using this trick in IPython:

```
import gc
import traceback

old_collect = gc.collect

def new_collect(*args, **kwargs):
    traceback.print_stack()
    old_collect(*args, **kwargs)

gc.collect = new_collect
```

Note it works only if the code does `import gc`, it does not work with `from gc import collect` (we are manipulating the gc module).

Please report a bug if you find out.